# Which are the most extreme artificial environments that lifeforms/ecosystems have adapted to?

Tags: adaptation, extremophiles

I have heard of ['extremophiles'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremophile), lifeforms that naturally thrive in all sorts of extreme environments.

Is there any evidence to suggest that lifeforms are adapting to the extreme environments (such as in mining waste, nuclear waste etc) that result from human activity?

Comment: This seems to be two questions. Are you interested in adaptations to extreme environments in general, or do these have to be recent adaptations to man-made conditions. If it is the latter then I don't think you will get any examples since all the "best extremes" have already been around for millions of years. You mention mining as an example, but of course there have been geological extremes since the birth of the planet.

Comment: @AlanBoyd good point, with this in mind, I think adaptations to extreme envirinments in general will be more than adequate. These can be inferred to modern environments.

Comment: [This looks relevant](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1388550/).

Comment: @AlanBoyd indeed that is the kind of thing I am interested in.